# Add 16 and 32 Bit numbers in X86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit

Let's have a unsigned 16 Bit number at the register bx and a 32-Bit number at eax:

```
    mov bx,3
    mov eax,10
    
    add eax,bx ; Producing an error
```

How can I add those numbers and store them in the EAX-register?
How can I expand the 16 to 32 Bit to finally add them?

Comment: x86 does not support adding numbers of different size. You'll have to make them the same size before you can add them. For example, you could expand bx from a 16-bit number to a 32-bit number.

Comment: Look at how GCC compiles a function that adds `int16_t` and `int32_t` args; https://godbolt.org/  / [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: The approach to binary operators with dissimilar operand types (sign or width) is to convert (widen) one (or both operands, when necessary) to a type that will hold all values of both operand types, and then the problem is reduced to doing arithmetic on this chosen type.

Comment: Use movsx or movxz (depending on whether the number is signed or unsigned)  to extend the shorter number before adding.

Comment: I believe @fuz meant to say movzx there.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Correct, sorry for the typo.